# How to send text from JTextArea to some email, using Java

Tags: java, email

I have GUI window for users to write their feedback, comments, etc. in JTextArea component.
What I want to do is for user send this text they typed via email when they press the button Submit.

What classes should I use to achieve this?
I googled it but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base API to use for email in Java is [JavaMail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/). It's not the nicest of APIs, though, and you may want to consider another API on top of it, such as [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) or [Spring Mail](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/mail.html).

Comment: thank you, I downloaded JavaMail from java.sun.com but I can't install it properly :(
I have the newest JDK and I'm using NetBeans 6.7.1

Comment: It doesn't need installing, it's just a JAR file.